# Wanting to have a shop without images

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images

I am wanting to set up a shop with product lists (under categories), but do not require images. Every theme I've looked at has images for products. In each row of the list I would like: Product Name, Brief Description, Unit, Price, Add to Cart. Any clues as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this `via .xml` for example in your **custom theme**, **child theme** or **module**.

The documentation explains containers and blocks in detail here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

Edit: actually you may not be able to remove the product image using xml, so you could copy the

> Magento_Catalog/template/catalog_category_list.phtml

template to your theme and edit it.